# Egg Substitute for binding agent

Tags: substitutions

Im making a meatloaf for someone who’s allergic to eggs. Any ideas on what I can use as a binding agent?

Comment: What meat are you using in your meatloaf?

Comment: Do you want to eat it hot or cold? If cold, fat could be used. That wouldn't work so well if served hot.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of egg less meatloaf recipes on the web.  Most use bread and milk as primary source of binding.

Comment: A panade doesn’t really have much binding power. I was hoping for more.

Comment: @RonTrunk  https://cookthink.com/egg-replacement-in-meatloaf-19-best-substitutes/   ...I'm not sure I would put most of these items in my meatloaf, though that is a personal preference....I don't think you give up much by leaving the egg out and working with the panade.

Comment: I saw that, and I agree most wouldn’t go in meatloaf. Maybe others have ideas.